# Entity Framework, relation between two tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

My model classes are:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Polls = new List<Poll>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    ICollection<Poll> Polls { get; set; }

}

public class Poll
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PositiveCount { get; set; }
    public int NegativeCount { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

}

public class PollsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Poll> Polls { get; set; }
}
```

EF created a table User_Id column for Polls table.
In the Create view of the Poll,  I want to specify the UserId for new poll belongs too, but intellisense shows there is no access to model.UserId, there is a model.User.Id, which is not allowing me create a Poll for existing user and rather creates new User with new Id and no association is created.

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Id)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Id)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Id)
</div>
```

What is the right way of creating a new Poll for an existing User then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Poll
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PositiveCount { get; set; }
    public int NegativeCount { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Poll` class should look like:

```
public class Poll
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PositiveCount { get; set; }
    public int NegativeCount { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public int User_Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

}
```

If you have a column in your `Poll` table `User_Id`, then your model should also have this column. You can then just assign a `User_Id` to a `Poll` and Entity Framework will take care of the correct linking to the right `User` object.

Further, consider making your association properties (Poll.User and User.Polls) virtual in order to use the lazy loading mechanisms of Entity Framework.
See [this](http://vincentlauzon.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/entity-framework-4-1-deep-fetch-vs-lazy-load-3/)

Comment: I will try what you are suggesting. I'm just confused because the User_Id column is actually there and model doesn't give access to it. Would you know why ?

Comment: tried what you suggested and now EF created User_Id column without any association and User_Id1 as FK to Users table.

Comment: What version of EF are you using? Code first or the "ordinary" one with the edmx mapping file (I dont know the name for that)?

Comment: @Chuchelo: Use `UserId` as the name of the FK property in `Poll` entity and try it again.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, Now EF created the column UserId_Id and result is the same.