# How to show relationship between two model in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Model relationships in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911844/model-relationships-in-asp-net-mvc)

I have two tables. one is Country and other one is region.
country table has regionId.
one country has one region and one Region has many countries.

In the list of country view I want show country name and region name.
and also edit view I want to show region list.

This is my country model.

```
public partial class CountryModel : BaseNopEntityModel,
    {           

        public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

This is my Region Model

```
  public partial class  RegionModel :BaseNopEntityModel
    {         

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }


    }
```

How do I set the relationship between these two model?

Comment: Simular topic on - [Answer here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467338/entity-framework-relation-between-two-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link each country with its associated region by making property of RegionModel class in CountryModel class.Through this property you can access a region against each country.

```
public class CountryModel : BaseNopEntityModel,
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Regionmodel Region{get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use a separate dto to store country with associated region, and you can change country model as following to fetch both country info and region list for select from drop down when editing.

```
public class CountryDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string RegionName { get; set; }
}

public partial class CountryModel : BaseNopEntityModel,
{           
    public CountryDto[] Countries { get; set; }

    public string[] RegionList { get; set; }
}
```